# Sass map.get() doesn't work. map-get() does. What gives?

Tags: function, dictionary, sass, syntax, sass-maps

## Problem: `map.get()` doesn't work. `map-get()` does work.

I set up a map of color values and created a simple function to retrieve them.

While doing the retrieval, I followed the [Sass documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/maps) which states that you can retrieve a map value using the `map.get()` function. Using this or any other `map.function` results in an `Error: There is no module with the namespace "map".`.

Checking out the map module, I noticed an alternative syntax, `map-get()`, which does work.

What gives? Am I missing something, like importing the map module, so that I can use it in that form?

*Check out my code below:*

```
// Using npm dart `sass 1.26.11`.

$colors: ('primary': black, 'secondary': white);

// Doesn't work    
@function color($color) {
  @return map.get($colors, $color);
}

// Does work
@function color($color) {
  @return map-get($colors, $color);
}
```

### Question: What do I need to change to get the `map.get()` syntax to work?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I am having a similar issue as OP (using dart-sass v1.25.0), and only `map-get` works, `map.get` doesn't.

The documentation doesn't seem to be very clear on this, but the ([**Sass Module System: Draft 6**](https://github.com/sass/sass/blob/master/accepted/module-system.md#built-in-modules-1)) document on Github explains it better.

It seems like [Sass is moving on](https://css-tricks.com/introducing-sass-modules/) to using `@use` in favour of `@import` for better compatibility with native CSS, and in order to get access to `map.get` you now must explicitly import  the `map module` using the `@use` keyword.

#### So using OP's example, `map.get` should work:

```
@use "sass:map";

$colors: ('primary': black, 'secondary': white);

@function color($color) {
  @return map.get($colors, $color);
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked to me, I had to add the `@use "sass:map";` command to make it work. I don't get why this is not explicitly said in the documentation.

Comment: Still doesn't work for me using Jekyll's built in SASS compiler.

Comment: @KevinOswaldo Note sure if this was published to their docs when you posted. There is a "Heads up!" card at the top of this page: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules which explains this entire system of having global aliases `map-get(...)` and how the @use "sass:map" is the way forward.